# Amazon Redshift join variable duplicated with select *

Tags: sql, join, duplicates, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create a new table in Redshift

The code used to create a new table works on it's own but when I wrap it in create table it stops working

Invalid operation: column name "Number" is duplicated;

```
create table test
as
(select 
a.*
,b.*
from a
inner join b
on a.number = b.number
);
```

Any ideas what's happening? I don't want to specify every single column of b just so i can omit b.numbe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a view, you should really select the columns explicitly that you want.  However, if the only duplicated column is `number` you can get around this using `using`:

```
select *
from a inner join
     b
     using (number);
```

`Using` is smart enough to include only one version of the `join` column when you use `select *`.

Comment: Oh great this works but only if you use * instead of a.*,b.* ...

Comment: @Mobix . . . The documentation says you can:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FROM_clause30.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped. Could you explain why * works but not a.*,b.*?